# Get substring starting after a given string

Tags: java, string

```
Caused by: com.some.packge.MyCustomException: blah, blah, blah
```

How can I get Sub-String of the above String in such a way that I get just **blah blah** part.
I tried below but I get MyCustomException as well in my substring.

```
mainString.substring(mainString.indexOf("MyCustomException"));
```

Comment: Are you actually using exception classes? If so you might be able to use some of the built in functions to get that text.. e.g. exception.getMessage() or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
mainString = mainString.substring(mainString.indexOf("MyCustomException:") + "MyCustomException:".length());
```

You should check if the `String` contains `MyCustomException:` before you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use lastIndexOf(). Indeed my bad corrected now

```
mainString.substring(mainString.lastIndexOf("MyCustomException:") + "MyCustomException:".length());
```